# How to pass the UI control values as the parameters to the Controller in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, link-to

I met a problem of parameter passing in Rails.

I have an object named 'account' and another object named 'locale'. There is a one-to-many relationship between them. One locale can be mapped with multiple accounts.

On accounts/index.html.erb, I have a dropdown which will list all the available locales.
And I have a link below.

In expectation, when I clicks this link, the index method of account controller will be called and the value of selected locale id will be passed. And the index method will retrieve all the accounts belonging to that locale.

What blocks me is I have no idea how to pass that selected value of dropdown to the controller.

I only know the basic way of passing a parameter is:

```
<%= link_to 'Refresh', {:action => 'index', :fromvar => 'refresh', :selected_locale_id => '1'}.
```

And from controller, we can get it by:

```
params[:selected_locale_id]
```

But it is the case of a fixed value. How to deal with a dynamic UI control value as my case?

Does link_to support some javascript to be embedded?

My rails version is 3.2.13.

Any one has idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can either do this as a form, or as javascript in the onclick event of the link. I would recommend a form.

The following should get you started:

```
<%= form_for :index do |form| %>
  <%= form.select :locale_id, Locale.all %>
  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Be sure to add a `post` route to the index action to allow the form to submit.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I do not quite understand how to add a post route to the index action to allow the form to submit. I only have "resources :locales" and "resources :accounts" in routes.rb. Any change shall I apply in this file?